# excel link table range to value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm searching for a way to link the range of an Excel table to a specific number.

Let's say I have a table that has a range of A1:B10. I want to make the number '10' dynamic and link it to a number that is calculated from another sheet. Let's say cell F1 contains that number and the value is '20'. 
Is it possible to make a dynamic range so the table range changes to: A1:B(F1). Then my table would adapt automatically and this has to work in my file.

I prefer a formula instead of a macro in VBA, because I normally don't work with VBA.

Comment: Use the INDEX or INDIRECT formula.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure how you define a table dynamically without VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative is to use a dynamic named range which is what we used to do before tables. The range, enclosed by marching ants below, is defined as follows:

=OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$1,0,0,Sheet3!$F$1,5)

The top left cell is A1. It is as many rows deep as the number in F1 and 5 columns wide (which could also be made dynamic).

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I think it works now!

Comment: when i select the table and go to --> design --> change table size, I can enter the offset formula and the size changes. But after entering this the table size is set to the new values and the connection to the formula is lost. Can I keep this formula to work for the table size?

Comment: As far as I know (which may not be very far so don't take it as gospel) is that you can't do this without VBA. However, a named range does cover many of the attributes of a table. Thus, I think your choice is either a dynamic used range & formula or table & VBA.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I think I need the table/VBA in this situation because all other formulas are linked to the table ranges like: Table1[value] so the connection is lost if I don't use tables

Comment: Ok in that case I suggest you post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, INDIRECT is your way to make any formula dynamic / dependent on other cell values.

Say you want to sum range `A2:C2`. But the value `2` for `C` is located in Cell `G2`.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A2"&":C"&G2))
```

this is equal to write `=SUM(A2:C2)` in my example below.

[image]

If you set `G2` to 3 it would calculate `A2:C3` for this `=SUM(INDIRECT("A2"&":C"&G2))`.

---

If you mean Excel [table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c), I guess the answer is no with formula, probably with [VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087736/how-do-you-make-a-dynamically-sized-data-table).

Comment: Could that string concatenation be shortened to `"A2:C"&G2` ?

Comment: @Jeeped, you're so fast and I love it!! Yes, it could be shortened to: `=SUM(INDIRECT("A2:C"&G2))`, nice spot!!

Comment: Hi @Wizhi, I understand what you're telling me, but that is not the thing I'm looking for. In your example: select A1:C2 and insert table. In my original question I reffered to F1 and let's say that number is in your picture in cell G2. I need to link the number from G2 to the range of the table so when the number changes to 3, my table range changes A1:C3. The reason for this is that I have formulas in my table which refer to another sheet. If this sheet is expanded i want to expand my table with it.

Comment: Thanks, then I understand. I think the answer is no, not with formula only. I think the closest you might achieve is @SJR solution, which could be worth a try!. That could include a range you want to look at and would be the same size as the table. Therefore could the range change as the table change, but it wouldn't be linked to the table itself.